# Ember.js: How to integration test components that interact with ember-data models

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm building a relatively straight-foward `comment-list` component. I want to pass in the commentable model (say a `Post`) and have the component take care of creating, editing, deleting comments. Right now I pass around all the various actions and it's been extremely brittle.

How do I create a true instance of an Ember Data model in a component integration test?

My immediate thought was to import the model then `.create({})` it but that errors with `use this.store.createRecord() instead`

```
/* jshint expr:true */
import { assert } from 'chai';
import { describeComponent, it } from 'ember-mocha';
import hbs from 'htmlbars-inline-precompile';
import Post from 'ownersup-client/post/model';

describeComponent( 'comment-list', 'Integration: CommentListComponent', {
    integration: true
  },
  function() {
    it('renders all of the comments', function() {
      const model = Post.create({ title: 'title' });
      model.get('comments').createRecord({ body: 'One Comment' })

      this.render(hbs`{{comment-list model=model}}`);

      assert.lengthOf(this.$('.comment-list-item'), 1);
    });
  }
);
```

Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**General answer for people who are struggled with similar things related to injecting in integration tests.**

Everything depends on which version and solutions you have in your project.

When you have an integration test with `module`
(`import { module } from 'ember-qunit';`)

you can use `this.owner.lookup('service:store')` inside your test

for more information, there is a great article from Dockyard
https://dockyard.com/blog/2018/01/11/modern-ember-testing

Answer (score 7):

Among all Ember test helpers, the store is only available from `moduleForModel`.

Here's how this test helper does it ([source](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-test-helpers/blob/bc63036f1a1a4aa1f8ab0abb9228a26ebc99f63a/lib/ember-test-helpers/test-module-for-model.js#L27-L31)):

```js
  var container = this.container;
  var store = container.lookup('service:store') || container.lookup('store:main');
```

You can do the same inside your test. You can also put it into a helper so that you don't have to copy-paste a lot.

Note that it will only work for an integration test. You can turn any test into integration one by starting the app using the `startApp` test helper that is bundled with your Ember CLI boilerplate.

Answer (score 5):

The new ember mocha release 0.8.4 contains a new, public way to inject services such as the store.  There's a guides section coming soon with an example (see https://github.com/emberjs/guides/blob/master/source/testing/testing-components.md)

essentially, in your beforeEach you want add the following line: `this.inject.service('store');`, making the store accessible as `this.get('store')` in your tests.

Here's a link to the pull request for the new change: https://github.com/switchfly/ember-test-helpers/pull/105

Comment: **this.inject.service('store');
  let model = this.get('store').createRecord('fo');** just throws an error for me